# Unused \setbox0 in beamerbasedecode.sty

Tags: beamer, macros, boxes

Inside the source file `beamerbasedecode.sty` of `beamer` package, there are the following lines:

```
\def\beamer@stoptexts{| stop:0| }
{
   \catcode`\|=13
   \catcode`\:=13
   \catcode`\,=13
   \catcode`\.=13
   \catcode`\+=13
   \catcode`\-=13
   \catcode`\(=13
   \catcode`\)=13
   \catcode`\ =13
\gdef\beamer@masterdecode#1{% must be called within a group
\ifnum\catcode`\|=13\edef|{\string|}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\:=13\edef:{\string:}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\,=13\edef,{\string,}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\.=13\edef.{\string.}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\+=13\edef+{\string+}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\-=13\edef-{\string-}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\(=13\edef({\string(}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\)=13\edef){\string)}\fi%
\ifnum\catcode`\ =13\edef {\string }\fi%
\edef\beamer@@@temp{#1\beamer@stoptexts}%
\beamer@localanotherslidefalse%
\setbox0=\hbox{%
\expandafter\beamer@decode\beamer@@@temp%
\ifbeamer@localanotherslide\global\beamer@localanotherslidetrue\fi}%
}%
}
```

Where `\beamer@decode` is the real decoding macro. But I don't find where the `\box0` is used in the source file. Why we need to put `\beamer@decode` into the `\box0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The box is quite deliberately never used. The idea here that that `\beamer@@@temp` might contain material that gets typeset. Carried out inside a box, anything that does end up typesetting material causes no problem inside the document as the box is thrown away. All that is needed after this code is the results of the decoding, which are set globally so are available.

Comment: Joseph, a user might be wanting to use \box0 themselves.
So this setting of \box0 kills the existing contents.
You should allocate a \box register for such a purpose, when not protected inside a grouping.

Comment: @ozross-RRM As the code comment indicates, this is only called in a group